How to implement automatic failover between AWS Lambda and Docker backend in my frontend?
I have a web application with two backend services:
One running on AWS Lambda, the other running on Docker
Currently, I want my frontend (built with React) to:

Use Lambda as the default backend.
Automatically switch to the Docker backend if the Lambda backend becomes unavailable.

The ideal flow would be that if the frontend fails to connect to Lambda (after a timeout or error), it should try the Docker backend instead. However, I’m unsure if this approach of handling failover at the frontend is efficient or the best practice.
Is it a good idea to handle backend failover in the frontend like this? What can I do to ensure my site doesn't experience downtime due server failing.
I was thinking of storing both backend URLs in the frontend. Attempt to fetch data from the Lambda backend first. If the request fails, switch to the Docker backend and retry the request. Keep Lambda as the default for future requests unless it fails again. But it doesn't seem like the best of solution.

how many times you have experienced that Lambda service is down?

Yeah lambda is pretty darn reliable

It happened only once. but I want a failsafe in place in case it happens agains
